# CSS - div with bottom right "curvy" cut off corner

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi all, I want to create a div like the one you can see in the above image with bottom right and a more "curvy" cut off corner. The css I use below will create a totally cut off straight and sharp edged corder (courtesy of [css generators](https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/)). How to achieve this?

```css
.box {
  --g: #000, #0000 1deg 179deg,#000 180deg;
  --mask:
    conic-gradient(from 45deg at bottom 78px right 78px,var(--g)) 100% 100%/100% 100% no-repeat;    
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a small SVG filter applied to a container element and I will make the code for the mask easier. I have created [CSS Generators](https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/) and in some particular cases we can use an optimized code

```css
.box {
  --mask: linear-gradient(to top left, #0000 100px,#000 0);    
  -webkit-mask: var(--mask);
          mask: var(--mask);
          
   width: 400px;
   height: 300px;
   background: red;
}


.container {
  filter: url('#goo') drop-shadow(3px 3px 5px );
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="box"></div>
</div>


<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Related article for the SVG filter: https://css-tricks.com/gooey-effect/